# How to disable/hide widgets while processing happens in the backround - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on uploading images to Firebase.
once the upload button clicked `showDialog` will pop.

```
 showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {},
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(
            "Uploading...",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF051622),
            ),
          ),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(    ////////Widget 1
                "Upload time depends on your image sizes and network speed.",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13.0,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              SpinKitWave(  ///////widget 2
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                size: 40.0,
              ),
              Text(  ///////widget 3
                "Upload went really smooth",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            new FlatButton(   ///////widget 4
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: new Text("Okay"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```

How can I disable or hide the `widget 3` and `widget 4` while uploading happens, 
and how to hide/disable `widget 1` and `widget 2` once the upload finished.

PS: I'm a newbie to flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it by using **Visibility** widget

```
Visibility(
     visible:true/false,
     child:Childwidget()
     ....
)
```

Wrap the widget which you want to show/hide inside the Visibility widget and the through a variable you can give the true/false value to the visible atribute based on the conditions on background process.

Comment: This method won't work after updating the state of that value variable (bool).